# 'Not being able to' vs 'Being not able to' , which is grammtical?

Tags: adverb-position

which is grammatical between the two sentences below?

1. We end up not being able to deal with new situations.
2. We end up being not able to deal with new situations.

Comment: They are both grammatical. So is: *We end up being unable to deal with new situations.* Do you have a particular reason to question one of the constructions?

Comment: Thanks so much ^^ I just wondered about the exact position of the word 'not'. I thought #1 is more grammatical because 'not' usually comes before the gerund and 'be able to' is common fixed usage -  so it seems awkward to put 'not' between 'being' and 'able'~.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical.

Having said that, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20being%20able%20to%2C%20being%20not%20able%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20being%20able%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeing%20not%20able%20to%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the more *common* version is 1.

I personally prefer:

> We end up being unable to deal with new situations.

However, adding that phrase into a [new Ngram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20being%20able%20to%2Cbeing%20not%20able%20to%2C%20being%20unable%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20being%20able%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeing%20not%20able%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeing%20unable%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that 1. remains the most common.